# html tag attribute "data-setbg" is not working in React project

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm converting a HTML [website template](https://colorlib.com/wp/template/leramiz/) into a React project, in that template there is an attribute called data-setbg, but there is no standard html attribute provided, I wonder what kind of library or framework provide this ability to set HTML's element background image like that?

Comment: You might be interested to take a look on this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52087169/css-background-image-renders-as-urlundefined-even-though-i-defined-it-jsx/52088232?noredirect=1#comment91127206_52088232

Comment: @CRayen Thanks for the suggestion, I'm not sure if he/she is having the same problem that I did, I posted my solution to the thread anyway.

Answer (score 3):

it turns out the writer is using JavaScript to do a short cut and easy way for setting up the element background as image, I found this .js code within the templates:

```
    $('.set-bg').each(function() {
        var bg = $(this).data('setbg');
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + bg + ')');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works
Move all code into the `$(window).on('load',function(){...})`

[CSS background-image renders as url('undefined'); even though I defined it. (JSX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52087169/css-background-image-renders-as-urlundefined-even-though-i-defined-it-jsx/52088232?noredirect=1#comment91127206_52088232)