# Jinja extends doesn't load image

Tags: flask, jinja2

I'm using Flask for a small web app and having trouble to get my background image to display after extending using Jinja.

My layout.html contains a header:

```
    <!-- Header section -->
    <header class="header-section">
        <div class="header-warp">
            <div class="container">
                <a href="#" class="site-logo">
                    <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/logo.png') }}" alt="">
                </a>
                <div class="user-panel">

          {%if session.user_id %}
              <a href="#">Logout</a>
          {% endif %}

                </div>
                <div class="nav-switch">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!-- Header section end -->
<main>
  {% block main %}
  {% endblock %}
</main>
```

And in another html file, I want to extend the layout:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
  Register
{% endblock %}

{%block main%}
    <section class="hero-section set-bg" data-setbg="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/review-bg.jpg') }}">
```

However, the review-bg.jpg doesn't load and instead, I received a blank section. However, when I straight up copying the layout (not using extends anymore), the image loaded correctly. I double checked with (http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/img/review-bg.jpg) and the path correctly return the image.

Anyone can help explain to me why Jinja doesn't load the image after extending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in  `data-setbg` - it can be React script, look here:

[html tag attribute "data-setbg" is not working in React project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52214586/html-tag-attribute-data-setbg-is-not-working-in-react-project?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Or try to google "data-setbg is not working"

Comment: Yes, it was the script that was messing up

Answer (score 0):

Edit the extension to:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
  Register
{% endblock %}

{%block main%}
     <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/review-bg.jpg') }}" alt="">
```

Do you see the image now? If so (what I suspect), it's not jinja/flask related but something else is going on. If not, right click on the page in firefox and press view source. Where is the link pointing to?

Comment: yeah the image showed up if I put it in a <img> tag. However, I still can't figure out why set-bg is wrong